# Flash Builder (FlexPrintJob & PrintDataGrid) Chrome Shockwave error

Tags: google-chrome, datagrid, flash-builder, shockwave

I have an mx:application using the Flex 4.6.0 SDK and I’m having some issues with the FlexPrintJob in Chrome only. The FlexPrintJob worked fine in chrome, up until maybe a couple weeks ago (I made no changes to the code) and now I’ve started experiencing “Shockwave Crashes”.

While printing I’m using:

- first title page template
- middle section template to handle a DataGrid. This is using the PrintDataGrid and loops through the dataProvider to see if the data will fit on one page, if not it will create another.
- Terms and conditions last page template

**Problem**: I’ve narrowed it down to this, I’m getting the Shockwave Crash error in chrome when the data (for the middle section) exceeds one page and tries to create another. This just started happening, I’m guessing with a chrome update…Sorry if I left something out and my description is lacking detail. I can add more clarification if needed.

Any ideas what’s going on?

Thanks!

--moe

```
public function doPrint(): void {
    // Create a FlexPrintJob instance.


    var printJob: FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();

    // Start the print job.
    if (printJob.start()) {
        // Create a FormPrintView control as a child of the application.
        var thePrintView: FormPrintView = new FormPrintView();

        addElement(thePrintView);

        // Set the print view properties.
        thePrintView.width = printJob.pageWidth;
        thePrintView.height = printJob.pageHeight;
        thePrintView.horizontalAlign = "center";

        // Set the data provider of the FormPrintView  component's DataGrid to be the data provider of the displayed DataGrid.
        thePrintView.summaryGrid.dataProvider = summaryGrid.dataProvider;

        // Create a single-page image.
        thePrintView.showPage("single");

        // If the print image's DataGrid can hold all the  data provider's rows, add the page to the print job. 
        if (!thePrintView.summaryGrid.validNextPage) {
            printJob.printAsBitmap = false;
            printJob.addObject(UIComponent(mainPagePrint), FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH);
            printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
            printJob.addObject(UIComponent(terms), FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH);
        }
        // Otherwise, the job requires multiple pages.
        else {
            // Create the first page and add it to the print job.
            thePrintView.showPage("first");
            printJob.printAsBitmap = false;
            printJob.addObject(UIComponent(mainPagePrint), FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH);
            printJob.addObject(thePrintView);

            thePrintView.pageNumber++;

            // Loop through the following code  until all pages are queued.
            while (true) {
                // Move the next page of data to the top of the PrintDataGrid.
                thePrintView.summaryGrid.nextPage();
                printJob.printAsBitmap = false;
                // Try creating a last page.
                thePrintView.showPage("last");

                // If the page holds the remaining data, or if the last page was completely filled by the last   grid data, queue it for printing.
                // Test if there is data for another  PrintDataGrid page.
                if (!thePrintView.summaryGrid.validNextPage) {
                    // This is the last page; queue it and exit the print loop.
                    printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                    printJob.addObject(UIComponent(terms), FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH);
                    break;
                } else // This is not the last page. Queue a middle page. 
                {
                    thePrintView.showPage("middle");
                    printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                    thePrintView.pageNumber++;

                }
            }
        }
        // All pages are queued; remove the FormPrintView control to free memory.
        removeElement(thePrintView);
    }
    // Send the job to the printer.
    printJob.send();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking things apart one-by-one and figured out what it was - the issue was is the FormPrintView. I had some unneeded properties in my PrintDataGrid that I think were originally copied from my main datagrid in my application.

I'm not sure why it was working before and just starting acting crashing now, but either way I shouldn't have had some of those properties there in the first place.

thanks!

--moe

```
<mx:PrintDataGrid  id="summaryGrid" width="100%" height="100%" sizeToPage="true"
                  alternatingItemColors="[#f7f7f7, #ffffff]" alpha="0.8"
                  borderStyle="solid" borderThickness="1" color="#646262"
                  creationComplete="summaryGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event)" fontSize="9"
                  headerColors="[#ffffff, #e8e8e8]" headerHeight="25" paddingTop="5"
                  rowHeight="55" textAlign="center" wordWrap="true" paddingRight="-1" >
```